# Cannot save file from UploadFile control using Session

Tags: asp.net, file, session, file-upload

I try to upload file using UploadFile control and I cannot do this. Problem realise when I try to save file which I keep in session. First of all I assign UploadControl to session variable:

```
Page.Session["postedFile"] = fuUploadGeometry;
```

After that when I click on my Upload button and want to save this file:

```
((FileUpload)Session["postedFile"]).SaveAs(filePath);
```

I get error

```
cannot access a closed file
```

But when I invoke directly using FileUpload name

```
fuUploadGeometry.SaveAs(filePaht)
```

problem doesn't exist.

Why?? If enybody knows how solve this problem I will be grateful.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
The problem solved :)

I set in web.config

`<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="30480" requestLengthDiskThreshold="30480"`

and till now everything works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Session for this. It serves no purpose. And, as you have discovered, you can't use it beyond the request where it is submitted, anyway.

Just use the code that's working. That's how you are supposed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What Andrew said.  And by setting requestLengthDiskThreshold all you are doing is disabling buffering which will cause the server to consume more memory and everything to run slower.

I think the correct resolution is to use the SaveAs method to save the posted file to a temporary folder on the FIRST postback, and store the file path to the temp file in viewstate or session.

After any additional post back or redirect, especially if asynchronous threads are involved, the SaveAs function is not going to work if buffering is required; you will get the error "Cannot access a closed file".